# please help on double NSMutableArray issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I found very strange issue on `NSMutableArray`. First I create 1 `NSMutableArray` (`arrA`) and add object to it. Then I create another `NSMutableArray` (`arrB`).

Then I add `arrA` to `arrB`. Finally when I update data inside `arrB` then `arrA` update also. Code like below

```
[arrA addObjectsFromArray:dataBack];

[arrB removeAllObjects];
[arrB addObjectsFromArray:arrA];
```

After this `for` loop I found data `arrA` change like `arrB`

```
for (int i = arrB.count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (itemExLong > 0 && [[[arrB objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"IM_QtyPriceEx"] doubleValue] > itemExLong)
    {
        itemExLong = [[[arrB objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"IM_QtyPriceEx"] doubleValue] + itemExLong;
        itemTaxLong = [[[arrB objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"IM_QtyTax"] doubleValue] - itemTaxLong;
        data = [arrB objectAtIndex:i];
        [data setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",itemExLong] forKey:@"IM_PriceEx"];
        [data setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",itemTaxLong] forKey:@"IM_QtyTax"];

        [arrB replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:data];
        break;
    }
}
```

When I `replaceObjectAtIndex`, I found `arrA` data change. Please Help.

Comment: BTW - this issue has nothing to do with using mutable arrays.

Comment: Did you have a question?  Sounds like normal behavior.

Comment: is it mean no way to solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Both arrays contain pointers to same underlaying objects. So if you will change an object using a pointer in any array it will change object (not the pointer) and that object is same for both arrays.
If you want to keep to different copies of objects make a copy of objects before manipulating them.

If you have custom class then you add copying functionality you can do that by implementing `NSCopying`  protocol, to learn more about [NSCopying](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/)